# Not able to understand a command in perl

Tags: perl

I need help to understand what below command is doing exactly

```
$abc{hier} =~ s#/tools.*/dfII/?.*##g;
```

and `$abc{hier}` contains a path `"/home/test1/test2/test3"`

Can someone please let me know what the above command is doing exactly. Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of regular expressions?

Comment: Did you make any experiments to find out the effect?

Answer (score 3):

`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` is Perl's substitution operator. It searches a string for text that matches the regex `PATTERN` and replaces it with `REPLACEMENT`.

By default, the substitution operator works on `$_`. To tell it to work on a different variable, you use the binding operator - `=~`.

The default delimiter used by the substitution operator is a slash (`/`) but you can change that to any other character. This is useful if your `PATTERN` or your `REPLACEMENT` contains a slash. In this case, the programmer has used `#` as the delimiter.

To recap:

```
$abc{hier} =~ s#PATTERN#REPLACEMENT#;
```

means "look for text in `$abc{hier}` that matches `PATTERN` and replace it with `REPLACEMENT`.

The substitution operator also has various options that change its behaviour. They are added by putting letters after the final delimiter. In this case we have a `g`. That means "make the substitution global" - or match and change all occurrences of `PATTERN`.

In your case, the `REPLACEMENT` string is empty (we have two `#` characters next to each other). So we're replacing the `PATTERN` with nothing - effectively deleting whatever matches `PATTERN`.

So now we have:

```
$abc{hier} =~ s#PATTERN*##g;
```

And we know it means, "in the variable `$abc{hier}`, look for any string that matches `PATTERN` and replace it with nothing".

The last thing to look at is the `PATTERN` (or regular expression - "regex"). You can get the full definition of regexes in [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). But to explain what we're using here:

- `/tools` : is the fixed string "/tools"
- `.*` : is zero or more of any character
- `/dfII` : is the fixed string "/dfII"
- `/?` : is an optional slash character
- `.*` : is (again) zero or more of any character

So, basically, we're removing bits of a file path from a value that's stored in a hash.

Comment: I get the impression that the optional part next to `.*` is irrelevant (and I phrased the pattern explanation in my answer intentionally to not go into that detail). What do you think?

Comment: @Yunnosch, Yes, `/?.*` could be simplified to `.*`.

Answer (score 2):

This `=~` means "Do a regex operation on that variable."

(Actually, as ikegami correctly reminds me, it is not necessarily only regex operations, because it could also be a `tr`ansliteration.)

The operation in question is `s#something#else#`, which means replace the "something" with something "else".

The `g` at the end means "Do it for all occurences of something."
Since the "else" is empty, the replacement has the effect of deleting.

The "something" is a definition according to regex syntax, roughly it means "Starting with '/tools' and later containing '/dfII', followed pretty much by anything until the end."

Note, the regex mentions at the end `/?.*`. In detail, this would mean "A slash (`/`) , or maybe not (`?`), and then absolutely anything (`.`) any number of times including 0 times (`*`). Strictly speaking it is not necessary to define "slash or not", if it is followed by "anything any often", because "anything" includes as slash, and anyoften would include 0 or one time; whether it is followed by more "anything" or not. I.e. the `/?` could be omitted, without changing the behaviour.
(Thanks ikeagami for confirming.)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for your input. Sooner or later, when doing regex, I will start thinking in a "what would ikegami say" way... Meaning this as a compliment of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
$abc{hier} =~ s#/tools.*/dfII/?.*##g;
```

The above commands use regular expression  to strip/remove trailing  `/tools.*/dfII` and
`/tools.*/dfII/.*` from value of `hier` member of `%abc` hash.

It is pretty basic perl except non standard regular expression limiters (`#` instead of standard `/`).   It allows to avoid escaping `/` inside the regular expression (`s/\/tools.*\/dfII\/?.*//g`).

My *personal* preferred style-guide would make it `s{/tools.*/dfII/?.*}{}g` .

Comment: What is the difference between `/tools.*/dfII` followed by anything (as defined by the `.*` you omitted here) and `/tools.*/dfII/.*` ? You mention those two separatly, but I do not see a difference. I ask because I get the impression that the optional part (as indicated by the `?`) is irrelevant.

Comment: The first matches file of directory with name ending with. The second matches "sub-directories of"  (special case ".../X/" matches directory).

Comment: Are you saying that the behaviour of the regex operation would be different if the part `/?` would be removed? How?